# Use @PageableDefault with Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, pagination, spring-data-rest

The documentation of @PageableDefault says:

> Annotation to set defaults when injecting a
>   `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` **into a controller method**.

When using Spring Data REST, is there a way to set default values without defining a controller ?

Setting PageableDefault in the repository like below doesn't seem to work.

```
Page<Player> findAll(@PageableDefault(size=5) Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Solution for Spring and Spring-Boot

You may extend RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter configuration to set the default page size:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration repositoryRestConfiguration) {
            repositoryRestConfiguration.setDefaultPageSize(5);
    }
}
```

## Solution for Spring-Boot only

#### You may set the default size in application.properties:

```
spring.data.rest.default-page-size=5
```

#### Other Spring Data properties:

```
# DATA REST (RepositoryRestProperties)
spring.data.rest.base-path= # Base path to be used by Spring Data REST to expose repository resources.
spring.data.rest.default-page-size= # Default size of pages.
spring.data.rest.detection-strategy=default # Strategy to use to determine which repositories get exposed.
spring.data.rest.enable-enum-translation= # Enable enum value translation via the Spring Data REST default resource bundle.
spring.data.rest.limit-param-name= # Name of the URL query string parameter that indicates how many results to return at once.
spring.data.rest.max-page-size= # Maximum size of pages.
spring.data.rest.page-param-name= # Name of the URL query string parameter that indicates what page to return.
spring.data.rest.return-body-on-create= # Return a response body after creating an entity.
spring.data.rest.return-body-on-update= # Return a response body after updating an entity.
spring.data.rest.sort-param-name= # Name of the URL query string parameter that indicates what direction to sort results.
```

source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix

Comment: my bad, I only thought of spring-boot

Comment: added a non spring-boot solution

Comment: Works, but sets the default value for all repositories and all methods. I'm gonna wait for other answers and accept this one if no one has another solution. Thanks

Comment: How to set default value to Unpaged?

Answer (score 0):

When using RestResource annotated repository methods, one can customize the page size by intercepting the request and adding a default parameter value (if none present):

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class RestResourceDefaultPaginationFilter implements Filter {
    @Value("${rest.resource.custom.page.size}")
    private String pageSize;

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request) {
            public String getParameter(String paramName) {
                String value = super.getParameter(paramName);
                // if no size parameter defined on request, then use the configuration default
                if ("size".equals(paramName) && StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
                    return page.size;
                }
                return value;
            }
        }, response);
    }
}
```

Then register this filter for specific url patterns:

```
@Configuration
public class RestResourcePaginationConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<RestResourceDefaultPaginationFilter> paginationFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<RestResourceDefaultPaginationFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new RestResourceDefaultPaginationFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/myEntities/search/rest-resource-endpoint");
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

This can come handy when you want to have exceptions to the more general option described by alexbt.